# Finding the density and $E(X)$ of nth element in a sequence of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Let $X_1\sim U([0,1])$. We randomly choose a point $X_2$ from the interval $[0,X_1]$. Next, we randomly choose a point $X_3$ from the interval $[0,X_2]$ and so on.
>
> - Find a general formula for $f_{X_n}$ (the density function).
> - Find $E(X_n)$.

How do you approach such a problem?

Comment: I'd at least try doing the $n=2$ case explicitly, and see if that gave me any further ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the conditional probability density is: $f_{X_n\mid X_{n-1}}(x\mid y) = \frac 1 y\;\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;y), y\in(0;1)}$ for all $n>1$

---

We begin with the density of the first case, $f_{X_1}(x) = \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)}$

We observe the density of the second case: $f_{X_2}(x) = \displaystyle\int_x^1 f_{X_2\mid X_1}(x\mid y)\; f_{X_1}(y)\operatorname d y\; \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)} \\ \qquad = \displaystyle\int_x^1 \frac 1 y\operatorname dy \; \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)}
\\ \qquad = -\ln x  \; \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)}$

Continuing onto the third case we find: $f_{X_3}(x) = \displaystyle \int_x^1 f_{X_3\mid X_2}(y\mid x)\;f_{X_2}(x)\operatorname d y  \; \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)}\\ \qquad =\displaystyle \int_x^1 \frac{-\ln y}{y}\operatorname d y  \; \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)}\\ \qquad = \tfrac 1 2 \ln^2 x \; \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)}$

A pattern is starting to emerge.   Can you spot it?   Then use a proof by induction to confirm that suspicion.

Comment: I see. I wasn't familiar with conditional probability densities, but after reading the theory, your answer is clear to me now.